# Linux CLI find dir paths without their children - only parent paths as a result

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, path-finding, gnu-findutils

I have this dir tree:

```
/tmp/find-test/
├── one
│   ├── abc
│   │   ├── one
│   │   └── two
│   └── def
│       ├── one
│       └── two
└── two
    ├── abc
    │   ├── one
    │   └── two
    └── def
        ├── one
        └── two
```

and the same for find-test2

```
/tmp/find-test2/
├── one
│   ├── abc
│   │   ├── one
│   │   └── two
│   └── def
│       ├── one
│       └── two
└── two
    ├── abc
    │   ├── one
    │   └── two
    └── def
        ├── one
        └── two
```

If I issue:

```
find /tmp -ipath "*find-test*" -type d
```

I get:

```
/tmp/find-test
/tmp/find-test/two
/tmp/find-test/two/def
/tmp/find-test/two/def/two
/tmp/find-test/two/def/one
...
/tmp/find-test2
/tmp/find-test2/two
/tmp/find-test2/two/def
/tmp/find-test2/two/def/two
/tmp/find-test2/two/def/one
...
```

but I would like to get as a result only parent dirs without their children. The desired result should be just these two parent paths:

```
/tmp/find-test
/tmp/find-test2
```

and similarly if I issue command:

```
find /tmp -ipath "*one*" -type d
```

I would like to get only:

```
/tmp/find-test/one
/tmp/find-test/two/abc/one
/tmp/find-test/two/def/one
/tmp/find-test2/one
/tmp/find-test2/two/abc/one
/tmp/find-test2/two/def/one
```

Please note it is without for example:

```
/tmp/find-test/one/abc/one
```

since it is already held by

```
/tmp/find-test/one
```

script to replicate dir trees:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/find-test1/{one,two}/{abc,def}/{one,two}
mkdir -p /tmp/find-test2/{one,two}/{abc,def}/{one,two}
```

and find commands:

```
find /tmp -ipath "*find-test*" -type d
find /tmp -ipath "*one*" -type d
```

I would like to ask how to use the `find` command to get the desired result containing only parent paths matching the pattern.

I need to use `-ipath` switch so I can match paths with more conditions but still only the parent paths are desired result.

I'm using sh and bash.

Comment: Use `-iname` instead of `-ipath`

Comment: Why do you think the shell you're using matters? The `find` command is not part of the shell.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: @Barmar I thought I would need to wrap find command with a script

Comment: @Barmar is it possible to do it by using `-ipath`? I provided the most elementary example and there are some cases where I need to find only parent dirs but there are more wildcards in the path for example `/tmp/bar*/foo*/*baz*/`

Comment: You can use both `-ipath` and `-iname`. `-ipath` applies to the entire path, `-iname` applies to the final name in the path.

Comment: So `-ipath 'bar*/foo*' -iname '*baz*'`

Comment: @Barmar but it returns all matching paths including children instead of just parent paths, for example in my case `find /tmp -ipath "*one*" -iname "*one*" -type d` returns 10 results instead of just four `/tmp/find-test/one`, `/tmp/find-test/two/abc/one`, `/tmp/find-test2/one`, `/tmp/find-test2/two/abc/one`

Comment: @Barmar Ad: `find /tmp -iname "*one*" -type d` does not work as well as desired: returnsl also 10 paths instead of 4. But as mentioned i need to use `-ipath` instead of just `-iname` anyway

Comment: I see my misunderstanding. I didn't notice that you have `one` nested inside another `one`, and don't want both of them.

Comment: @Barmar You were right, there was no need to write any script :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-prune`. I  used your command to replicate the dir tree and issued your commands with `-prune`, which resulted in:

```
$ find 2>&- /tmp -ipath '*find-test*' -type d -prune
/tmp/find-test2
/tmp/find-test1
$ find 2>&- /tmp -ipath '*one*' -type d -prune
/tmp/find-test2/two/def/one
/tmp/find-test2/two/abc/one
/tmp/find-test2/one
/tmp/find-test1/two/def/one
/tmp/find-test1/two/abc/one
/tmp/find-test1/one
```